# Keep a Numpy array sort unchanged when it gets shuffled and noisy in an iteration

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I want to keep an `(n,2)` Numpy array's elements in place when it gets shuffled and gets some noise in a loop.

For example, I have a function which maps three points in 2D space from `[[100,30],[40,80][150,20]` to `[[39,82],[101,29],[152,21]]`. I want to sort the second array so that their euclidean distance from the first array is minimized. (Trying to keep track of points under this transformation).

Here is a sample of what this process may look like:

```
a = np.random.randint(1000,size=(10,2))
for i in range(100):
    b = a + np.random.randint(low=-2, high=2,size=(10,2))
    np.random.shuffle(b)
    a = b
```

(As you can see the noise amplitude is much smaller than the array values, 2<<1000)

I want to keep the initial order in the arrays.

Here is what I have done so far, but failed:

```
a = np.random.randint(1000,size=(10,2))
for i in range(100):
    b = a + np.random.randint(5,size=(10,2))
    np.random.shuffle(b)
    b_ = b.copy()
    for i in range(len(a)):
        dist = np.sqrt((a[i,0]-b[:,0])**2+(a[i,1]-b[:,1])**2)
        loc = np.argmin(dist)
        b_[i], b_[loc] = b_[loc], b_[i]
    b=b_.copy()
    a=b.copy()
```

But it somehow messes up array elements.

Comment: Which order are you aiming to keep if you shuffle one of the arrays?

Comment: @PaddyHarrison The initial order of a. In the example I provided, the first and second elements should be swapped. [[101,29],[39,82],[152,21]]

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be along the right lines:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[100,30],[40,80],[150,20]])
b = np.array([[39,82],[101,29],[152,21]])

# compute Euclidean distances between all points
dists = cdist(a, b)

# dists.argmin(axis=1) gets the index of minimum distance for each input a
b[dists.argmin(axis=1)]
>>> array([[101,  29],
           [ 39,  82],
           [152,  21]])
```